# Synaptic GUI shows no history

Tags: lubuntu, synaptic

The Synaptic PM runs fine and writes to the `/var/log/apt/history.log` file no problem.  But the menu selection [File -> History] brings up an empty window.

Is this a configuration thing?  Am I missing some `libxxx`?

synaptic 0.81.4 on lubuntu 15.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue on Ubuntu 15.10.
It worked flawlessly until Ubuntu 15.04.
Maybe it will work on Ubuntu 16.04 again.

**Workaround** to check history
Open a terminal and execute :

```
cat /var/log/apt/history.log
```

Reference : [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/synaptic/+bug/1487890)